# How can I remove just geometry instances added to primitives in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I saw some similar questions like how to remove all primitives and so, but none of the answers help me. I am loading several CZML files on my cesium, and at the same time I need to add some geometry instances, like the code that I provided here to my cesium file, using data from my CZML.

There are two situation in my model, in one of them I want to delete all of my primitives, data sources and entities, for which I used following `reset()` method. When I tried to remove primitives and entities, I've got `DeveloperError: This object was destroyed, i.e., destroy() was called.Error` and when I just delete primitive, it said some of entities already exist on the collection, which means it cannot delete all of entities.

In the second case, I just want to delete those geometry instances that I created but I want to keep other entities and data sources. If I delete all the primitives, I will lose some entities that I need.

I have a method when I am loading CZML for creating geometry instances as follows:

```
function createMap(West,East,South,North,hNumber,VNumber){
var baseSouth=South;
    var vdivid=(North-South)/VNumber;
    var hdivid=(East-West)/hNumber;
for (var i=0;i<hNumber;i++){        
    for(var j=0;j<vNumber;j++){
    var rectangleInstance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
      geometry : new Cesium.RectangleGeometry({
      rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees((West+j*vdivid), baseSouth,(West+(j+1)*vdivid) , baseSouth+hdivid)
      }),
      id : 'rectangle'+i+'.'+j,
      attributes : {
        color : new Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(getRandomColor(0.2))
      }
    });
    scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.GroundPrimitive({
      geometryInstance : rectangleInstance
    }));        
    baseSouth=baseSouth+hdivid;
}
};
```

My reset method is as follows,

```
   function reset(){
   clock.multiplier = 1.0;
   var primitives = scene.primitives.removeAll();
   viewer.dataSources.removeAll();
   viewer.entities.removeAll();
   };
```

getRandomColor is a function for generating some specific Cesium colors randomly. I define this method because I want to generate some specific random colors (for example just GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE and RED)

Comment: Off-topic comment here, but Cesium includes a [Color.fromRandom](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Color.html#.fromRandom) helper function built in.

Comment: Also, can you post a more complete example, showing how you tried to delete the primitives?

Comment: @emackey I updated the question, it has my reset function now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the reset function.  I believe the problem here is that your call to `scene.primitives.removeAll()` is removing primitives that belong to a dataSource.  But in this case, I think it's safe to simply re-order the removals.

Give this a try:

```
function reset() {
    clock.multiplier = 1.0;

    // First, remove all dataSources.  Removing a dataSource will
    // automatically remove its associated entities & primitives.
    viewer.dataSources.removeAll();

    // Next, remove any remaining entities that weren't part of a dataSource.
    viewer.entities.removeAll();

    // Finally, it is safe to remove any remaining primitives, as we can
    // now be certain they did not belong to any dataSource or entity.
    scene.primitives.removeAll();
};
```